# Spring Hibernate : error 400 "the request sent by client was syntactically incorrect"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

This is my semester.java class

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "semester")
    @NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Semester.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM Semester s")})
    public class Semester implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Integer id;
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "semesterid")
        private List<Marks> marksList;
        @JoinColumn(name = "facultyid", referencedColumnName = "facultyid")
        @ManyToOne
        private Faculty facultyid;
        @JoinColumn(name = "semesterid", referencedColumnName = "semesterid")
        @ManyToOne
        private Semestername semesterid;
        @JoinColumn(name = "subjectcode", referencedColumnName = "subjectcode")
        @ManyToOne
        private Subject subjectcode;

        public Semester() {
        }

        public Semester(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public List<Marks> getMarksList() {
            return marksList;
        }

        public void setMarksList(List<Marks> marksList) {
            this.marksList = marksList;
        }

        public Faculty getFacultyid() {
            return facultyid;
        }

        public void setFacultyid(Faculty facultyid) {
            this.facultyid = facultyid;
        }

        public Semestername getSemesterid() {
            return semesterid;
        }

        public void setSemesterid(Semestername semesterid) {
            this.semesterid = semesterid;
        }

        public Subject getSubjectcode() {
            return subjectcode;
        }

        public void setSubjectcode(Subject subjectcode) {
            this.subjectcode = subjectcode;
        }       
    }
```

This is the admin controller

```
    @Controller
    public class AdminController {

        @Autowired
        AdminDao adminDao;

     @RequestMapping(value="/addsemester",method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String addsemester(Model model){

            model.addAttribute("semesterlist", new Semester());
            return "semesterentry";
        }

         @RequestMapping(value="/addsemester",method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public String _addsemester(@ModelAttribute("semesterlist") Semester semester){

            boolean check = adminDao.insertsemester(semester);
            if(check){
                return "redirect:/addsemester";
            }
            else{
            return "dashboard";
        }
        }
    }
```

This is the admindaoImpl.java class and when i used to insert the semester 400 error with the syntically incorrect was faced.

```
    @Repository("adminDao")
    public class AdminDaoImpl implements AdminDao {

        @Autowired
        SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional
         public boolean insertsemester(Semester semester){
              boolean check = false;
            try {
                sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(semester);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            if(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(semester)!=null){
                check = true;
            }
            return check;
         }

    }
```

and when i try to insert the data to database i got 400 error. and i have check all the value of jsp name with database again i got a problem on these.

Comment: 400 has nothing todo with the dao. It is an http error. You call the Controller in a wrong way. How you call it?

Comment: i also check this i called using  <form method="post" action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/addsemester">   and in controller the above "/addsemester" is used. any solution

Comment: Add the complete Form to your question please.

Comment: <form method="post" action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/addsemester">    
<input type="text" name="semesterid" placeholder="Semester ID"/>
<input type="text" name="facultyid" placeholder="Faculty ID"/>
 <input type="text" name="subjectcode" placeholder="Subject code"/>                             
<input type="submit" value="add" /> 
<input type="reset" value="cancel"/>
</form>

Comment: Where is the attribute semesterlist here?

Comment: semesterlist is called from the above get method model.addatrribute("semesterlist", new Semester());

Comment: try to use `(@ModelAttribute Semester Semester)`

Comment: i have add as per your suggestion but same error. <form method="post" action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/addsemester" modelAttribute="semesterlist">

Comment: i have done by replacing the foreign key model with the simple model and i knew the problem was due to use of foreign where in model private Subject subjectcode is adsorbed and i have replace with the string and i solve this problem and thanks for giving a time to correct the problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `modelAttribute` in  `<form:form` tag instead of `<form`.

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="semesterlist" action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/addsemeste‌​r" > 
<form:label path="semesterid">Semester ID</form:label> 
<form:input path="semesterid"/>
 <!-- provide the rest of fields --> 

<input type="submit" value="add" /> <input type="reset" value="cancel"/> 
</form:form>
```

And in controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addsemester",method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public String _addsemester(@ModelAttribute("semesterlist") Semester semester){
...........
}
```